# .net - Consumer driven contracts for SOAP/XML?

Tags: c#, .net, pact

I would like to apply the [consumer driven contracts](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) methodology to a .net system composed of several web services. Some of the services are exposed in REST but most of them are WCF services exposed as SOAP.

For this I would like to write consumer driven contract tests and the only available framework for .net, at the moment, is [PactNet](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net) - the .net version of [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/).

Unfortunately, AFAIK, PactNet only supports REST based services at this time.

Given the above, what would be the most cost-effective approach for implementing consumer driven contracts for SOAP/XML services in .net?

Comment: Hey, if you're going to vote close, can you please explain why? Thank you.

Comment: "Is there a tool for X" questions fall under [number 4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. Reframed my question as per link provided.

Comment: Did you manage to get use PACT to talk to your SOAP services?

Comment: @iasksillyquestions sorry, no.